# RecyclerView inside Fragment inside ViewPager intercepting others pages events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

So the problem is pretty simple, I have a ViewPager which contains 5 different fragments, each one having a RecyclerView. I can swipe pages, they are displayed with their own data.

The thing is I can only scroll first RecyclerView (page 0). When I try to scroll on another page it doesn't in that page, but in the first one. Same for item clicks.

Anyone already encountered that problem? I can post code if demanded

Thanks

Comment: please post code, or we don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your concern CrowsNet, I figured out what it was.

It was caused by my ViewPager transformer, I was using the library

```
compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'
```

When I use the library it seems that the ViewPager updates the views and selected items but all touch events stay in the first page. Then I did a custom ViewPager transformer (updated from https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and it works fine. So I just got rid of the library, I only need one transformation.

The code of onCreate in my activity

```
@UiThread
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    // other declarations
    [...]

    // ViewPager and Tabs initialization
    mHomePageAdapter = HomePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    view_pager?.adapter = mHomePageAdapter
    view_pager?.offscreenPageLimit = 4
    view_pager?.setOnTouchListener(this)

    // works, the one from Google, updated : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58918
    view_pager?.setPageTransformer(false, DepthPageTransformer(), ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE) 

    // doesn't work - from library
    view_pager?.setPageTransformer(true, FlipHorizontalTransformer(), ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE) 

    // note that I've tried every combination of the function setPageTransformer (1, 2, 3 arguments)

    tab_layout?.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
    val onTabSelectedListener = HomeTabSelectedListener()
    tab_layout?.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener)
    onTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(tab_layout?.getTabAt(0)!!)

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    selectedPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("selected_page")
    }
    view_pager?.currentItem = selectedPage

    [...]
}
```